# Section headers in Century Gothic, text in Garamond

Tags: fonts, sectioning

I'm trying to comply with the following graphical profile in a LaTeX2e document. Ideally, I'd like to specify all these things in a package, which I can then import to instantly comply with the specifications.

> Header 0 (document title): Century Gothic Bold, 20 pt, caps
>   Header 1: Century Gothic Bold, 16 pt
>   Header 2: Century Gothic, 14 pt
>   Header 3: Century Gothic Italic, 12 pt
>   Text: Garamond, 10 pt
>   Captions: Garamond Italic, 12 pt

I've been looking around to find a way to use the Century Gothic font in LaTeX, but found nothing useful. The only examples I've found require XeTeX, which I don't know and would like to avoid having to learn just for this.

How do I implement these specifications using LaTeX2e?

*(Importing more packages is of course completely OK, as long as they are publicly* available.)

Comment: This is probably stating the obvious, but [URW Gothic](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/avantgarde/) (an Avantgarde clone) comes pretty close to Century Gothic.

Comment: @lockstep: Coming "pretty close" is unfortunately not good enough, as I'm making an attempt on using LaTeX while still complying with the graphical profile of our organization. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you have these fonts installed on your system, by far the easiest way to do this is with XeLaTeX.  There is very little to learn about XeLaTeX; it's just regular LaTeX with one package (`fontspec`) which allows you to load any font on your system.  The rest of the problem simply reduces to using a few regular packages to specify the various element formats.

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX      Must use XeLaTeX to compile
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode  File must be encoded at UTF-8
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{caption}
% commands from fontspec
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Garamond}
\newfontfamily\headingfont{Century Gothic}
% commands from titlesec
\titleformat*{\section}{\headingfont\fontsize{16}{18}\selectfont\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\headingfont\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\headingfont\itshape}
% commands from titling
\pretitle{\begin{center}\headingfont\fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
% commands from caption
\DeclareCaptionFormat{plain}{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont\itshape#1#2#3\par}
% regular make title commands
\title{A title}
\author{An author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{A section}
Some text.
\begin{figure}[h]
A figure.
\caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}

\subsection{A subsection}
Some more text.
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
Some more text.

\end{document}
```

I'll leave putting this into a package as an exercise.  (See the `clsguide` docmentation for all the basics.)  I've also added semi-arbitrary values in the second argument of the `\fontsize` commands; you should adjust them to what you require.

[image: output of code]

Comment: Sorry I haven't seen this in a while - I started working on something else, and this fell out of my scope. Now I'm back, and will give this a try.

Comment: I get to `\setmainfont{Garamond}` where it complains that I don't have the font. I've tried `garamond` as well, with the same result. Synaptic Package Manager claims that the package texlive-fonts-extra is installed, and that it contains the font garamond. (I haven't been able to find Century Gothic, though...) Do you know where I can obtain these fonts for Ubuntu 11.04?

Comment: Both of these fonts are distributed with Microsoft Office (at least on the Mac, which is how I have them.) I don't think they are free fonts.

Comment: That does indeed seem to be the case. I tested with some other fonts, that I did have installed, and it worked perfectly - so the problem now boils down to getting access to the fonts themselves, which is another matter than what this question was about. Thanks

Comment: As a note to any future readers of this post: on my system (Ubuntu 12.04) it turned out Garamond was installed as "Garamond-Normal" - when I changed it to that, everything worked.